# Last question about logs.

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

**QUESTION**

> Solve:
>
> $$\log_{\frac 1 2} (x+1)^{ \log_2x+1}=0.3$$

**Attempt**

$\frac {\log( x+1)}{\log 2}$  multiply $\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log 2^{-1}}$.

Sorry! but thanks.

[image]

---

Comment: First, I took the exponent log base 2 (x+1) and placed it as the coefficient of log log base 1/2 (x+1) . Then, I used changing of base and obtained the result listed above.

Comment: @HiDanny  Please use LaTeX. I's hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: I probably should added that image in the beginning. Sorry.

Comment: @HiDanny Please take the time to examine my edit to understand how to type in $LaTeX$ if you plan to make more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this identity: $log(a^{b})=b*log(a)$ for any base.

$$ log_{1/2}((x+1)^{log_{1/2}(x+1)})=log_{1/2}(x+1)*log_{1/2}(x+1)=.3$$

Take the square root of both sides:

$$log_{1/2}(x+1)=\pm(.3)^{1/2}$$

Raise 1/2 to the power of each side:

$$x+1=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\pm\sqrt{.3}}$$

$$x=-1+2^{\pm\sqrt{.3}}$$

Comment: What happened to the other log_{1/2}(x+1)? The one in the first line that you multiplied

Comment: I took the Square root. of both sides.

Comment: I added the sign ambiguity to the square root as well.

Comment: I see. Thanks you!

Comment: The OP needs to ensure that both solutions satisfy the equation. Maybe one of them only applies.